# Interfacing with an HID Device from C#/C++?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7, keyboard-events, hid

I understand that I can hook events sent by HID devices, but I am interested in finding out if there is any way to actually send instructions to it. For example, I would like to write an application that allows me to click a button, and the keyboard "presses a key". None of the normal methods (SendInput, SendKeys, etc) are working for my needs, so this is about the only option I have left.

Is this even possible, and if so what should I be looking into? Thanks!

Comment: What is your HID controller? a micro/FPGA or something?

Comment: I am using a Logitech G15 Gaming Keyboard

Comment: Thought it is worth mentioning that the Windows On-Screen Keyboard seems to work partially as well. Once I input with the keyboard into the game, the keys from the On-Screen Keyboard work for about 5 seconds. I have no idea why this is, but might make figuring it out a bit easier.

Comment: Why does `SendInput` not work?

Comment: I gave this a try http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com and it worked for everything except what I need it for (input in a game). It was strange because it even worked in the textbox in the game, but as far as any type of movement or actions, nothing happened at all.

Answer (score 2):

As none of the normal methods would work, I have opted to use the Oblita Interception Library which seems perfect for my needs. Thanks for the help!

http://oblita.com/Interception